# qiskit VQC with Amplitude Encoding for state preparation

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I am trying to implement a Quantum Neural Network in qiskit, using the VQC class.

The problem is that each data consists in 190 features, which just can't be encoded with the default VQC's function (ZZfeatureMap), since this would mean create a circuit with 190 qubits.

The solution that I would like to adopt is the Amplitude Encoding, which would allow me to use only 8 qubits (with 256 amplitudes = 190 features + 66 zeros).
How can I implement a parameterized circuit in qiskit that performs this ?

I tried with the following (as an example on 2 qubits), but just doesn't work:

```
custom_circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
x = ParameterVector('x', 4)

custom_circ.initialize(x)
```

**EDIT:**

My problem is not with the parameteres, but with the Amplitude Encoding.
Usually, if I need to Encode a vector of 4 numbers in 2 Qbits, I just do the following:

```
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
vector = [0.124, -0.124, 0.124, 0.124]
circuit.initialize(vector)
```

In this way I encode my vector as amplitudes of the Qubits.
But now I need to parameterize this (the vector is not fixed).
The problem is that the "initialize" function doesn't accept parameters:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> [...]
>
> File "D: ... \qiskit\extensions\quantum_initializer\initializer.py", line 455, in initialize
>
> return self.append(Initialize(params, num_qubits), qubits)
>
> File "D: ... \qiskit\extensions\quantum_initializer\initializer.py", line 89, in **init**
>
> if not math.isclose(sum(np.absolute(params) ** 2), 1.0,
>
> TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'Parameter'

Is there a way to create and amplitude encoding that is also parameterized?

**EDIT 2:**
I resolved the problem, Thank You.
If you want to parameterize the Initialize circuit just use [RawFeatureVector](https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/stubs/qiskit_machine_learning.circuit.library.RawFeatureVector.html#qiskit_machine_learning.circuit.library.RawFeatureVector).

Comment: Glad you figured it out, sorry I misunderstood your question!

Answer (score 2):

You can build parameterized circuits in qiskit using the [`Parameter`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.Parameter.html) class. Here is an example:

```
In [1]: from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
   ...: from qiskit.circuit import Parameter

In [2]: custom_circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
   ...: theta = Parameter("\u03B8")
   ...: custom_circ.rz(theta, range(2))
   ...: custom_circ.draw()
Out[2]: 
     ┌───────┐
q_0: ┤ RZ(θ) ├
     ├───────┤
q_1: ┤ RZ(θ) ├
     └───────┘
```